# Stopping Timer from another class

Tags: java, timer, jbutton, actionlistener, actionevent

Basically this code gets called from a JButton(in another class) to move the cube by repainting it over and over again. I wish to create another JButton to stop the timer (timer.stop()) from another method. How would i do that

```
private ActionListener actionListener ;
public void moveCube()
{
    actionListener  = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            cube.moveBox(7,5);
    repaint();
        }
    };
    Timer timer = new Timer( 100, actionListener );
    timer.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to make the `Timer` object available outside of the `moveCube()` method.

In other words: in your code, define `Timer myTimer;` at the top, and assign it in the `moveCube()` method: `myTimer = new Timer( 100, actionListener );`. Then, you can call the timer from your other button.

Comment: will do! theres always that delay!

Answer (score 0):

Make a singleton for an object class that have Timer for that timer make get/set functions. After that get your instanceClass.getTimer().stop(); ofcource you have to set it in your first class....